Flight Gear and Numb Bat
Can't get Flight Gear to load on 24.04 Ubuntu, Numb Bat cat /proc/version results in

Linux version 6.8.0-38-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-049) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42) #38-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jun  7 15:25:01 UTC 2024

The results of /var/log/syslog:
2024-07-11T08:42:37.181406-05:00 GarageBoy systemd[2034]:
Started snap.flightgear.flightgear-c2cfabc4-e1bc-43d2-b00e-05771812a847.scope.
2024-07-11T08:42:37.189824-05:00 GarageBoy kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1720705357.188:323): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap"
profile="/snap/snapd/21759/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=11933 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
2024-07-11T08:42:37.548418-05:00 GarageBoy systemd[2034]: run-rede0f5bf908b4f7b8446d6e24c3b44f0.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
2024-07-11T08:42:37.548854-05:00 GarageBoy systemd[2034]: run-rede0f5bf908b4f7b8446d6e24c3b44f0.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.


Please contact the upstream developer.

I see you are running the Snap version of Flight Gear, which is running afoul of Apparmor, FG seems to be tryin something needing the net_admin (12) capability. I see no reason for a __game__to need this capability. Contact the Flight Gear developers. Or, uninstall Fligt Gearband install the .deb version.

I will look for a tarball.
